# JavaScript Web Speech API when to use .start() as opposed to .speechstart()?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I am trying to create a web application using the Web Speech API where at the start the user clicks a button to start the  speech recording. I am trying to have it stop automatically when the user stops talking, then I want to use the Google Translate API to translate the speech from the user. I have included the code for the Web Speech portion that I am having issues with.

```
if (window.webkitSpeechRecognition) {
  recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = false;
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var i;
    return $('#transcript').text($('#transcript').text() + ((function() {
      var _i, _ref, _ref1, _results;
      _results = [];
      for (i = _i = _ref = event.resultIndex, _ref1 = event.results.length - 1; _i <= _ref1; i = _i += 1) {
        _results.push(event.results[i][0].transcript);
      }
      return _results;
    })()).join(''));
  };

  $('#startStopButton').on('click', function() {
    if (this.innerText === 'Start') {
      this.innerText = 'Stop';
      recognition.lang = 'en-AU';
      return recognition.speechstart();
    } else {
      this.innerText = 'Start';
      return recognition.speechend();
    }
  });
} else {
  alert('Cannot access the speech recognition API.  Are you using Chrome 25+ ?');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With regard to speech recognition:

First, you should set your `SpeechRecognition` object's `continous` property to `false` (or not set it to `true`, since `false` is the default value)

```
recognition.continuous = false;
```

(this should enable end-of-speech detection, i.e. recognizer will stop after detecting end-of-speech)

Also, your click-handler code seems strange: the Web Speech API defines `start()` and `stop()`, but you seem to use `speechstart()` and `speechend()`... I would suggest, you use

```
recognition.start()
```

and

```
recognition.stop()
```

also these function do not have a return value, so no need using `return recognition.start()`.

In order to keep your button label in sync, I would suggest to add handlers for `onend` and `onerror` e.g.

```
recognition.onend = function(event){
   $('#startStopButton').text('Start');
};
```

For more details have a look at the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#api_description)